# Generating samples on an exponential distribution

Tags: python, exponential-distribution, synthetic-data

I am trying to generate a synthetic earthquake database where the number of events ($N$) with magnitude ($M$) in the range $[M, M+\delta_M]$ follows:
$\log_{10}(N) = a - bM$
where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

I am trying to do this in Python using the "random" module. I know I can (or at least I think I can - as I haven't tried it) use random.expovariate but I thought I could use random.random with a transformation like:

```
-math.log10(random.random()))
```

The random function generates numbers between 0 & 1.

I ran this for 2,000,000 samples which I then binned into 0.1 bins and plotted on a log scale.

[image]

I'm not worried about the variation above x=4.5. This is due to small number of points and natural randomness. What I am asking about is the very small (at this scale) variation for the points near x=0 - particularly the point at x=0 which appears to be lower than the fitted (by eye) line.

[image: generated data]

Given the large number of events in this bin the expected error should be very low.
When I look at the difference between the generated and theoretical values I see that points below x ~2.5 start to deviate from linearity.

[edit]
Have now changed the red line to represent what my simulation should be generating. The following plot shows the deviation between my simulation and the theoretical points.

[image: diff between observed and theory]

To try and work out where my problem lies I wrote code that generated numbers from 0 to 1 with a very fine step. Each number then went through the function noted above. The result was a purely linear result that exactly matched the theoretical values. So my transformation function is fine - so I'm thinking it's just something to do with the random number generator?

Would be grateful for any pointers. Thanks.

Comment: (1) What exactly does the red line represent? (2) On what basis have you determined the values "start to deviate from linearity"?  The fit looks great.

Comment: The red line has the slope of the "b" in the formula and the "a" adjusted (by eye) to fit most of the points. As x decreases, the number of simulations rises exponentially so the fit (to the straight line) should get better and better.The final point (x=0) is clearly off the fitted line. I could add another plot showing the deviation but its shape depends on the choice of the a&b-values.

Comment: Fitting by eye is not a valid way to assess data.  The red line should be drawn to represent the distribution you are simulating from.

Comment: @whuber - Agreed. So have modified the red line to represent the theoretical distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The plot of residuals (deviations between the observed and theoretical frequencies) was inspired, because it shows what is going wrong.

You have generated $n$ independent random numbers according to some distribution function $F$ (defined as $F(x)$ is the chance each number is $x$ or less).  You then binned them into the intervals $(-\infty,0.1],$ $(0.1,0.2],$ and so on, and tallied the counts in each bin.  Your plots indicate the bin locations (horizontal axes) and the counts (or related values) on the vertical axes.

**It is important to get both parts of the comparison correct:** you need to generate the random values in a way that follows the intended distribution $F$ *and* you need to compute the theoretical counts in the bins.

Your graphics suggest you haven't computed the expected counts correctly, so I will discuss this in detail.

The expected count of values lying in some bin $(a,b]$ is the expected count of all values $b$ or smaller, minus the expected count of all values $a$ or smaller.  This will be proportional to $F(b) - F(a).$  In the present case you have generated uniform random values $U$ in the interval $(0,1]$ and taken their common logarithms $X = -\log_{10}U.$  Thus, for any positive number $x,$

$$F(x) = \Pr(X \le x) = \Pr(-\log_{10}U \le x) = \Pr(U \ge 10^{-x}) = 1 - 10^{-x}.$$

Consequently

$$\Pr(X \in (a,b]) = F(b) - F(a) = (1 - 10^{-b}) - (1 - 10^{-a}) = 10^{-a} - 10^{-b}.$$

Because each number $x_i$ in your simulation is generated independently, the expected count of values in a bin $(a,b]$ (with $a \ge 0$) therefore is

> $$\begin{aligned}
> e(a,b) &= E\left[\# x_i\mid a \lt x_i \le b\right] = n\Pr(a \le X \le b) = n(F(b)-F(a))\\
> & = n(10^{-a} - 10^{-b}).
> \end{aligned}$$

For $n=2.2\times 10^6$ and the bins you use, these expected counts are

$$(452477.9, 359416.0, 285494.2, 226776.1, \ldots).$$

They drop below $1$ beginning with the 58th bin $(5.7, 5.8].$

**I ran this simulation (in `R`).**  Although my random numbers must differ from yours, my results should be qualitatively the same.  Here they are, in graphics.

First, **here are the counts shown as vertical bars** (erected at the right endpoint of each bin) and the expected values shown as a connected red curve:

[image: Figure 1]

Next, because on a semi-log plot the expected values all lie on a common line, **here is the same plot with a logarithmic vertical axis:**

[image: Figure 2]

It's hard to tell how good the agreement is because the logarithms compress variation among the highest counts so much.  **Your residual plot of differences between the counts and their expectations gives a clearer comparison:**

[image: Figure 3]

*(To make this plot I combined all the counts in the rightmost bins because none of them was expected to have more than five values each.)*

Sure enough, there's much more variation at the left.  *But this is to be expected,* because (to an incredibly good approximation) *the variation in a random count is [proportional to the square root of its expectation.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/493749/919)*  This variation is called the [*standard error* of the count.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/31571/919)  Consequently, to make a fair comparison of these residuals, we "standardize" them by dividing by their standard errors and redo the plot:

[image: Figure 4]

Now the residuals randomly oscillate among positive and negative values -- some counts are a little high, some a little low -- but they show no tendency to be larger in any sequence of bins, nor do they show any tendency to have runs of positive or negative deviations.  ***This is strong evidence that the simulation conforms with the expected distribution.***

One simple way to assess this evidence is called a [chi-squared test.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/17148/919)  In this application we simply sum the squares of all the $m$ residuals shown in the plot and compare that value to a [chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution) with parameter $m-1.$  In the simulation I have shown, this sum of squares is $42.23$ and $m=51.$  In a $\chi^2(51-1)$ distribution, $22.5\%$ of the probability is less than $42.23$ and the remaining $77.5\%$ is greater: this places the chi-squared statistic squarely in the middle of the distribution.  That means there's nothing unusual about the value of $42.23;$ consequently, *despite having generated over two million random values, there still is no evidence their distribution differs from the theoretical (that is, intended) distribution.*

I suspect that when you perform this analysis with your data, you will arrive at the same conclusion.